# Are there any way to treat Javascript methods like ClojureScript functions?

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I like ClojureScript, but to interop between CLJS and Javascript is difficult. I would like to create a function that can perform date culculations in arbitrary units, such as the following. But this code results in errors. Is it not possible to treat JS methods like `.foo` like functions?

```clj
 (defn date-add [date num unit]
    (let [[getter setter]
          (case unit
            :sec [.getSeconds .setSeconds]
            :min [.getMinutes .setMinutes]
            :hour [.getHours .setHours]
            :day [.getDate .setDate]
            :month [.getMonth .setMonth]
            :year [.getFullYear .setFullYear])]
      ;; such as (.setDate date (+ num (.getDate date)))
      (setter date (+ num (getter date)))
      (js/Date. (.getTime date))))
```

Though I know great libraries like `deja-fu` or `cljs-time`, the avobe is the example. I would like to be able to perform simple operations on dates without using a library.

Comment: If you wrap each function in a lambda, it will work: `#(.getSeconds %)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gives you a path (I'm not convinced it's great):

```clj
user> (let [f js/Date.prototype.getSeconds]
        (.call f (js/Date.)))
46
```

Comment: I didn't know that I could reference JS methods like this in ClojureScript as well. thank you.